# Calling a JDBC servlet onload of a form from a select option

Tags: jsp, servlets, jdbc

I have a JSP page in which i have included java beans for DB connection using JDBC for a select option. Now i want to do the same using servlet. JDBC connection code is there in Servlet. JSP page has a select option and i need database value in it on form load. I have searched but most examples are using struts and ajax. I do not need struts yet and since it is on form load and does not depend on change of select option, i am not able to get through it.

JSP page (relevant piece of code):

```
<%
//Connectivity code which works, just mentioning setAttribute
 pageContext.setAttribute("authors", rt);
%>  

 <form name="foo">
<td >Shipper</td>
 <td >
<FONT COLOR=WHITE> to </FONT> <select name="database1" style= "width: 150px">
<c:forEach var="item" items="${authors}">
<option>
<c:out value= "${item}" />
</option>
</c:forEach>
</select>
</td>
</form
```

Servlet: "ZServlet.java"

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
ArrayList<String> rt = new ArrayList<String>();
    //Same JDBC connection code as in JSP page beans
     request.setAttribute("authors", rt);
    }
```

Now my doubt is on how to replace beans by accepting attribute authors from servlet into select option during form load.

Thankful for all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is to summarize what was missing from code while trying to forward data from servlet to JSP page:

Relevant piece of code in JSP Page, "Index.JSP":

```
<body>
 <form name="foo">
<table>
<tr>
 <td >Shipper</td>
<td >
<FONT COLOR=WHITE> to </FONT> 
<select name="database1" style= "width: 150px">
<c:forEach var="item" items="${authors}">
<option>
<c:out value= "${item}" />
</option>
</c:forEach>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
</form>
</body>
```

Relevant piece of code in servlet:

```
public class ZServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

//JDBC Connection code, not relevant here.

ArrayList<String> rt = new ArrayList<String>(); /*"rt" holds string of column data spooled during JDBC connection*/

 request.setAttribute("authors", rt);   

 RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("Index.jsp");
                 view.forward(request, response);

} //Servlet "ZServlet" ends.
```

web.xml relevant piece of code, within  tag: This was missing and i had to manually add it:

```
<servlet>
          <servlet-name>ZServlet</servlet-name>
          <jsp-file>/Index.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>
```

Regards.

Comment: If finally you will post your answer then why are you asking from us? Please visit [stackoverflow tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read how stackoverflow works.

Comment: @Braj i am sure i dont get any points for my correct answers. I marked my answer correct for an accurate future reference for others, because that sums it all. Obviously your 1st solution added a big contribution and i have mentioned that but it would never work without a proper servlet mapping. And i have given 1 up to your answer. I am really thankful for your help.

Comment: It's obvious that you have to add mapping in `web.xml`. If I delete my post then will does your post make sense? Have you visited the link that I shared you.

Comment: I don't know what mapping are you talking about. It's complete unclear and not complete. Do you think it will help other without providing any mapping in your post? Why and what mapping is required?

Comment: @Braj servlet mapping to JSP is what i am speaking about.That did not happen automatically, and i had to do it manually.I am really thankful for your post as i have mentioned. It happens that sometimes web.xml has not mapped servlets and JSP and we do it manually. i had done till setting the attribute in servlet (as shown in original post) and it would have never worked without you showing me how to forward that request with attribute. people can miss out on simple stuff due to original configuration error and may have to manually map, as in my case. & that wud b last in their minds.Thankyou.

Comment: Can you update your answer with the mapping as well.

Comment: @Braj Yes, thats sensible. I am adding it.

Comment: @Braj I have added your piece of code in my final answer. However, i do feel that the different methods you explained to achieve the task was really useful. Anyways, Thankyou much for all your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution 1. Servlet -> JSP

Simply call the Servlet first that set the authors list as request attribute and then forward the request to the JSP.

Servlet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    ArrayList<String> rt = new ArrayList<String>();
    //Same JDBC connection code as in JSP page beans

    request.setAttribute("authors", rt);
    RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("authors.jsp");
    view.forward(request, response);
}
```

JSP:

```
<form name="foo">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Shipper</td>
            <td><FONT COLOR=WHITE> to </FONT> 
                <select name="database1" style="width: 150px">
                    <c:forEach var="item" items="${authors}">
                        <option>
                            <c:out value="${item}" />
                        </option>
                    </c:forEach>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

#### Solution 2 JSP -> Servlet

First call the Servlet form JSP where set the authors as request attribute and read it in JSP.

Servlet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    ArrayList<String> rt = new ArrayList<String>();
    //Same JDBC connection code as in JSP page beans
    request.setAttribute("authors", rt);
}
```

JSP:

```
<jsp:include page="/authorsServlet" />

<form name="foo">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Shipper</td>
            <td><FONT COLOR=WHITE> to </FONT> 
                <select name="database1" style="width: 150px">
                    <c:forEach var="item" items="${authors}">
                        <option>
                            <c:out value="${item}" />
                        </option>
                    </c:forEach>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

#### Solution 3 jQuery (AJAX)

JQuery is good way to load the data asynchronously that result into a better user experience. In the above two solutions the entire JSP page will not load until and unless the response is not returned from the Servlet that adds a delay to generate the user interface.

It's very simple code. Simply write the authors name in the response stream as comma separated in Servlet and split it in JSP when response is returned back.

Sample code:(*read inline comments for more information*)

Servlet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    ArrayList<String> rt = new ArrayList<String>();
    //Same JDBC connection code as in JSP page beans

    PrintWriter writer=response.getWriter();
    writer.print(<comma separated list of author names>);
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
}
```

JSP:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() { // When the HTML DOM is ready loading, then execute the following function...
        // Handler for .load() called.
        $.get('servletURL', function(response) { // Execute Ajax GET request on URL of "someservlet" and execute the following function with Ajax response...
            alert(response);
            var $select = $('#database1'); // Locate HTML DOM element with ID "someselect".
            $select.find('option').remove(); // Find all child elements with tag name "option" and remove them (just to prevent duplicate options when button is pressed again).
            var items = response.split(',');

            for ( var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                $('<option>').val(items[i]).text(items[i]).appendTo($select); // Create HTML <option> element, set its value with currently iterated key and its text content with currently iterated item and finally append it to the <select>.
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<form name="foo" id="foo">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Shipper</td>
            <td><FONT COLOR=WHITE> to </FONT> <select id="database1"
                style="width: 150px">
            </select></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Thankyou, your solution works.. Its just that servlet mapping in web.xml had to be done too, manually. When i applied what you suggested(1st method) and then mapped servlet to jsp in web.xml (manually), it worked.
Thanks.